# Text in pre element not showing when > 65535 characters Chrome, safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, pre

I have a <pre> element I'm filling with a large amount of text (about 72000 characters in this case). In chrome and safari, I notice that the text inside the <pre> is getting divided in two at the 65535 character mark. I can tell this because in the inspector, I can select the two blocks of text similar to how I can select an element.

You'd think that in this case, you would see the first 65535 characters, but instead, I'm actually seeing the second block of characters, while the first 65535 characters are hidden. I think this is because the text inside the element contains escaped XML.

Is there any way around this character limit for the text inside a <pre> element?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes have maximum memory limit, which in this case seems to be 65535 bytes. Therefore when you have text larger than that - it will be placed in two text nodes.

Not sure what do you mean by `"while the first 65535 characters are hidden"`, I tried it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/valentinas/dv99r/1/ and it looks fine on Chrome 23.

Comment: Plain text works. Thanks for helping me narrow it down - turns out the text I'm putting in the &lt;pre&gt; contains escaped XML characters. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you want to put it up on jsfiddle.net? That way people could properly investigate it, now I can just guess that you have some uncapped stuff in there too.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with one line being longer than 65535 characters long. Happens with lorem ipsum too: http://jsfiddle.net/valentinas/dv99r/2/ are line breaks important in your output? It looks like xml, so adding line breaks every 50.000 characters or so should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in PRE there is a line length limit of 80 characters. A single newline is required to break line within paragraph. To break a paragraph exactly two newlines are required.

If text/plain is reflowed it should still follow paragraph structure rather than just break long lines. However necessary for mobile devices, this is still problematic.

By default it should not break and should scroll lines sideways.

This precedent for plaintext goes way back to tele-printing and is the basis for programming and compiler input. Break it like Micro-Soft and I will get very annoyed.

If the app has a limit of 64kio it could be changed to break on paragraph so they are not split.